# Wrap SCORM interaction in TinCan statements: is that possible?

Tags: scorm, tin-can-api

I have TinCan LRS and tons of SCORM content. So instead of using SCORM server-side stuff for storing learning results, I want to alter SCORM player so it would issue TinCan statements to my LRS.
Is this theoretically possible?

I clearly understand that I should rewrite SCORM player, providing custom RTE handler.

I don't know SCORM very well, please warn me if there are any potential pitfalls.

Comment: There is also a brief but fine guide: http://tincanapi.com/scorm-to-tin-can-api-cookbook/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to map SCORM calls to the Experience API (aka Tin Can). A quick Google search returns this, which should give you some pointers: [Converting SCORM packages to Tin Can API](http://tincanapi.co.uk/pages/SCORM_to_Tin_Can_API.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. I should improve my google skills.